# Android Profiler does not load?

Tags: android-studio, android-profiler

Android Profiler in my android studio does not load the details on running the app in the emulator.

I have tried running the app in debug mode, restarted emulator, android studio and PC as well. Nothing worked.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The developers have fixed it. Just update.